# pytest-mock combined with pytest-qt: call mock after function has executed

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock, pytest-qt

I would like to call the function that is mocked before the mock is called. What is the best way to do this?

**main.py**

```
import logging
import sys

import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, app: QApplication):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = app
        self.resize(330, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Window 1")
        self.button = QPushButton("Button")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
        self.message_printed = False
        def button_clicked() -> None:
            self.display_message("Hello, world!")
        self.button.clicked.connect(button_clicked)

    def display_message(self, msg: str) -> None:
        logging.info(f"Message: {msg}")
        # Some complex code here...
        self.message_printed = True

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow(app)
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    main()
```

This test does not pass, since the mock is called instead of the mocked function (not after):

**test_main.py**:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

from main import MainWindow

def test_message(qtbot, qapp, mocker):
    window = MainWindow(app=qapp)
    qtbot.addWidget(window)
    window.show()
    with qtbot.waitCallback() as callback:
        mocker.patch.object(window, "display_message", callback)
        qtbot.mouseClick(window.button, Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton)
    assert window.message_printed
```

However, the following test works but I would like to know if there is simpler (more elegant) way to do this:

**test_main2.py**:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

from main import MainWindow

def test_message(qtbot, qapp, mocker):
    window = MainWindow(app=qapp)
    qtbot.addWidget(window)
    window.show()
    with qtbot.waitCallback() as callback:
        def gen_wrapper():
            original_method = window.display_message
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                original_method(*args, **kwargs)
                callback(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        wrapper = gen_wrapper()
        mocker.patch.object(window, "display_message", wrapper)
        qtbot.mouseClick(window.button, Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton)
    assert window.message_printed
```